# Run class continuously in the background in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ethernet

I have an application that requires running a class continuously, this class allows to obtain numerical information of a *scale* connected to the ethernet network.

I would like to obtain the weighing in real time and keep it running.

The class I want execute on continues is `PLC_READER`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private class PLC_Reader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String ret = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                SimpleLogixCommunicator comm = new SimpleLogixCommunicator("192.168.1.253", 0xAF12);
                Object q = comm.read("ScaleWeightT");
                ret = q.toString();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                ret = "Exc";

            }
            return "end";

        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtV);
            tx.setText(ret);
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use service class for background service.

Comment: you should use forground service